# Magento customer account page times out, how to debug?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Some recent changes have caused customer account page to become unusable on my Magento website, when I click on it browser loads for awhile and then returns The connection has timed out error in the browser. I have set up display errors in index.php file and SetEnv is set to true in htaccess file, however I get no error messages nor I see anything in system.log file.

Can someone please direct me into the right direction how to debug this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: In my opinion debugging is part of programming and my question is how to debug this particular problem. It is not necessarily  a Magento related problem, it could be a PHP, MySQL or Ubutnu problem as well.

Comment: Then please post your code that has changed and the code for the page that isn't working.

Comment: That is the problem I don't know what, where and why has changed my question is how to debug such problem. I am guessing it could be two things: some layout xml file got corrupted somewhere or there is a problem with htacess file, but then again I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case was that HTTPS was turned on in Magento admin panel.

I was looking at Magento error and exception logs and even looked at mysql logs but never looked at apache logs, that's were the error was thrown.

Two things can resolve this problem:

1) Installation of SSL certificate
2) Set Use Secure URLs in Frontend to 'No' in admin panel located in System>Configuration>Web>Secure

Hope this answer helps someone out there with same problem :)